# Obtaining places based on proximity query against zip code

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, proximity

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to accomplish a specific type of `Google Places API` request.

I have a `zipcode` and i want to find out if there are `any hospitals within 20 miles of the zipcode`

I found the following example `maps` code and changed the request to `hospitals` but that didnt perform what i wanted.

So, to summarize, i just want an api request i can convert to `PHP` that contains an array of available hospitals within 20 miles of a zip code else an empty array. I could also take as an output just a boolean of yes hospitals exist or false otherwise

```
    var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.867, 151.195);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {center: sydney, zoom: 15});

    var request = {
      query: 'hospitals',
      fields: ['name', 'geometry'],
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, function(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker(results[i]);
        }

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    });
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) or [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) services would be more appropriate for your use case, since you want to get multiple hospitals and not just one (Find Place returns a single place only).

Try the below code sample which displays hospitals within 20 miles of `Pyrmont NSW 2009`. Note that location must be a `LatLng` object, it can't be a zip code, but with Text Search you can add it to your query. Then set the `type` to `hospital`.

```
var map;
var service;

function initialize() {
    var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 13
    });

    var request = {
        location: pyrmont,
        radius: '32186',
        query: '2009',
        type: 'hospital'
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}

function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        title: place.name
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!